# Simple Airtable formula syntax error - If statement to output 3 options

Tags: if-statement, airtable

My simple is pretty simple. I want a field within Airtable to be populated with something based on the contents of another field.

Here's what I have so far (which I know is incomplete, but I can't even seem to get the simple syntax right):

`IF( {Ordered Products} Contains ("cocktail table") AND Contains ("stool"), "Yes", "N/A" )`

In plain English what i want to happen is if the 'Ordered Products' cell contains the string 'cocktail table' and the string 'stool' then the field value should be yes.

Ideally I then want if the string 'cocktail table' IS present and the string 'stool' is NOT present the field value should be no.

Else the field value should be N/A.

Thanks in advance for any help :)